# Oracle- Variável sem dados

Tags: sql, oracle, funções

Tenho um problema e uma dúvida ao mesmo tempo, fiz uma função para ver pedidos faturados e declarei uma variável da função assim:

```
select filsaida
  into v_loja
  from mov_itped where pedido= p_pedido and status <> 6;
end ;
```

Quando tem algum registro que corresponde à cláusula `WHERE`, a função retorna normal, mas quando não retorna registro, dá o erro ORA-01403: dados não encontrados.

Comment: Poderia colocar a função? Ou a declaração e a parte do `return`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numa condição "into" você precisa obrigatoriamente retornar apenas um registro. Se retornar vários vai dar a exceção ORA-01422, e se retornar nenhum vai dar a exceção que você citou.

Se você possuir um valor padrão, para sua variável quando não existir o registro você pode utilizar um bloco de exception tratando a exceção NO_DATA_FOUND. Ex:

```
Declare
  numero integer;
begin
  begin
    select 1 into numero 
      from dual 
     where 1 = 2;
  exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
      numero := 0;
  end;
  dbms_output.put_line(numero);
end;
```

Comment: Opa amigo vlw pela ajuda, o exception funcionou certinho tentei colocar um valor padrão para variável mas não tinha dado certo tinha usado `CASE` e `IF ELSE` os dois não funcionar estava ficando doido kkk.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade, uma forma bem simples de contornar este problema é ao invés de colocar select 1 para qualquer coisa, coloque select Count(*) para qualquer coisa, pois o Count, caso a cláusula where não seja atendida ja vai voltar 0 zero, caso contrário retornar 1, ai você pode tratar o zero como negativa e o >0 com positivo.